# How to solve the time complexity of this question

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
for (int j = 1 to n) {
  k = j;
   while (k < n) {
    sum += a[k] * b[k];
    k += log k;
   }
 }
```

The answer I got was `n^2/log(j+10)` which can be simplified to `o(n^2)` but the answer is supposed to be `O(n^2/log(n))`. Can someone explain the answer?

Comment: When k=j=1, you add log k = 0, so that's an infinite loop...